# How to conditionally add new XElement into an existing root element in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I created an `XElement` by this way:

```
private void Analyze( IEnumerable<XElement> inputData)
{

    XElement rootElement = new XElement("Items",
    from singleInputItem in inputData
    select new XElement("Element",
         new XAttribute("ID", "default ID"),
         new XAttribute("Type", "default type"),
         new XElement("Width", 120),
         new XElement("Height",150)
         ));
}
```

Also I created a simple function like this:

```
private int contentNumber = 0;

private void getContent()
{
    return contentNumber++;
}

private bool status = false;
//some function to change status here
```

Now I want to add a new `XElement` into `rootElement` within `Element` when `status` is `true`, so I want to do something like this:

```
private void Analyze( IEnumerable<XElement> inputData)
{

    XElement rootElement = new XElement("Items",
    from singleInputItem in inputData
    select new XElement("Element",
         new XAttribute("ID", "default ID"),
         new XAttribute("Type", "default type"),

         if( status == true )
         {
             new XElement("Content", getContent());
         }

         new XElement("Width", 120),
         new XElement("Height",150)
         ));
}
```

Obviously, the above `if` part isn't correct. But I couldn't find any solution to do the same thing on the internet. Could someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a so-called `ternary operator` for this:

```
condition ? 'value if true' : 'value if false';
```

or, in your case:

```
...
    new XAttribute("Type", "default type"),
    status ? new XElement("Content", getContent()) : null,
    new XElement("Width", 120),
...
```

Answer (score 0):

[wit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414473/wit) is correct. But in case if you don't want to include status field at all if status is false, then you will have to initialize `rootElement` conditionally as follows:

```
private void Analyze( IEnumerable<XElement> inputData)
    {
        XElement rootElement = null;
        if(status)
        {
          rootElement = new XElement("Items",
          from singleInputItem in inputData
          select new XElement("Element",
               new XAttribute("ID", "default ID"),
               new XAttribute("Type", "default type"),
               new XElement("Content", getContent());     
               new XElement("Width", 120),
               new XElement("Height",150)
             ));
        }
        else
        {
          rootElement = new XElement("Items",
          from singleInputItem in inputData
          select new XElement("Element",
               new XAttribute("ID", "default ID"),
               new XAttribute("Type", "default type"),     
               new XElement("Width", 120),
               new XElement("Height",150)
             ));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I also tried this and it worked:)

Comment: It works.  But this is higher maintenance and duplicate code.  The ternary null vs new XElement would be preferred IMHO.